# Reset countdown on Celery task

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I need to have a celery task run after a countdown, but be able to reset that countdown under certain conditions. For example, I want to call `apply_async` with `countdown=15`, but if certain event occurs before the task is executed, I'd like to set that countdown to 15 seconds again.

From the docs and googling I think I could accomplish this by saving the task id, and then revoking and recreating the task if the event occurs. I was wondering if there's a more elegant approach to it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the countdown can't you just revoke this task and create a new one?

Comment: Well as I said that's what I came up with after reading the documentation, but at the time it didn't feel right so I was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use some cache, such as Redis, to store some lock key. When you call apply_async increment value of the key. When you execute this task in celery - decrement this value. If value is 0 - execute the task. So if there was two calls of apply_async your counter will be 2 and first execution of task will be skipped.

I think [this code can help you](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial).